# Why ajax post didn't work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

```
    $("#MainContent_btnSave").click(function (e) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    $('#myDiv').text(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "send.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The javascript code above is javascript function, which is called by clicking on button with id=MainContent_btnSave.

The same request with parameter GET finish successfully.

But with parameter POST xmlhttp.status always equal to 405 and arise error like that: "Command HTTP POST, used to 'send.php', is denied."
What can be the problem?

File 'send.php' contain :

```
    <?php
   echo "Your email was sent!";
    ?>
```

Comment: what is `send.php` like?

Comment: You're using jQuery..so use it, jQuery comes with a `$.ajax` function

Comment: File 'send.php' contain :  
<?php
   echo "Your email was sent!";
    ?>

Comment: shouldn't 'xmlhttp.send();' be xmlhttp.send(null); Also give the entire url not just 'send.php'

Comment: I have tried the entire url and got the same result. The problem perhaps isn't in url because the 'get' request instead of 'post' request work correctly with both variants of url. Thanks for suggestion:)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery then use it's functions. $.post() for example:

```
$("#MainContent_btnSave").click(function() {
    $.post('send.php', data, function(response) {
         $("#myDiv").text(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not an answer for my question.

Answer (score 2):

> parameter POST xmlhttp.status always equal to 405 and arise error like that: "Command HTTP POST, used to 'send.php', is denied."

A 405 error is Method Not Allowed. This means either: your webserver is blocking the POST request, or your PHP framework is blocking it, or doesn't have a POST route defined for send.php.

Comment: Why my webserver could block my POST request? How can I allow to perform POST request?